# How to solve this system of trigonometric equations?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I wanto to express $x$ and $y$ as a function of the known parameters $a, b, c, d, p, q$. The angles $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are unknowns, but not of interest for me:

$$
\begin{align}
a &= x \cdot \cos(\phi_1) + y\cdot \cos(\phi_2) \\
b &= -x \cdot \sin(\phi_1) -y\cdot \sin(\phi_2) \\
c &= -x \cdot p \sin(\phi_1) - y \cdot q\sin(\phi_2) \\
d &= -x \cdot p \cos(\phi_1) - y \cdot q \cos(\phi_2)
\end{align}
$$
All variables are real, $p$ and $q$ are positive.

How do I do this? Even though I had a couple of higher math courses in college, I didn't encounter trigonometric systems of equation once.

An additional piece of information that might be relevant: I am actually only looking for $x^2$ and $y^2$, so I don't care about any ambiguities because of a $\pm$-solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the middle two equations as a system of linear equations in the two unknowns $x\sin\phi_1$ and $y\sin\phi_2$. So with just those two equations you can find the values of $x\sin\phi_1$ and $y\sin\phi_2$.

Similarly, use the other two equations to solve for $x\cos\phi_1$ and $y\cos\phi_2$.

With those four values you can calculate $x^2$ and $y^2$.